# Defragmenting File Programatically On Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, filesystems, fragmentation

I am attempting to follow this tutorial: [Defragmenting Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/defragmenting-files).

I call `DeviceIoControl()` with `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP` on a handle to the `C:` volume, and I get a proper response.

I then open a handle to another file (I tried files from 10KB to a few MB) successfully, then I call `DeviceIoControl()` with `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS`, and it succeeds with no last error or failed result, but the `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` is not filled.

I also tried calling it on the `C:` volume handle, but it keeps returning  `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF` even after trying to set the `OVERLAPPED` offset to 0, and setting the file pointer with `SetFilePointer()` to 0 relative to the beginning of the file.

```
BOOL dic(HANDLE dev, DWORD code, LPVOID in, DWORD ins, LPVOID out, LPDWORD outs)
{
    HANDLE h = GetProcessHeap();
    DWORD s = 1000;
    DWORD r = 0;
    out = HeapAlloc(h,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,s);
    while (!DeviceIoControl(dev, code, in, ins, out, s, &r, 0))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError() || ERROR_MORE_DATA == GetLastError())
        {
            s *= 10;
            LPVOID t = HeapReAlloc(h, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, out, s);
            if(!t){
                HeapFree(h, 0, out);
                return 0;
            }
            out = t;
        }
        else
        {
            HeapFree(h, 0, out);
            printf("dic unk: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 0;
        }
    }
    *outs = s;
    return 1;
}

BOOL getvolptr(HANDLE volh, PRETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb, LPDWORD rpbs)
{
    STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER vcn = { 0 };
    return dic(volh, FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, &vcn, sizeof(vcn), rpb, rpbs);
}

    RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb = { 0 };
    DWORD rpbs = 0;
    ULONGLONG cluster_cnt=0;
    HANDLE fi = openfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Kernel32.dll");
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fi)
    {
        printf("failed to open file! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    r = getvolptr(fi, &rpb, &rpbs);
    if (!r)
    {
        printf("failed to get vol ptrs! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rpb.ExtentCount; ++i)
    {
        cluster_cnt = (ULONGLONG)(rpb.Extents[i].NextVcn.QuadPart) - (ULONGLONG)(rpb.StartingVcn.QuadPart);
        printf("%d) size: %llu clusters (0x%016X)\n", i, cluster_cnt, rpb.Extents[i].Lcn.QuadPart);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the first `HeapAlloc()` for failure. And `HeapFree()` can wipe the last error code from `DeviceIoControl()` before you print it.

But more importantly, you are not passing the `out` data back to the caller correctly, so you are leaking the allocated memory, and the caller ends up with garbage for output.

Since the caller is passing in their own `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` to receive the data, you need to copy the contents of the allocate memory into that buffer, eg:

```c
BOOL dic(HANDLE dev, DWORD code, LPVOID in, DWORD ins, LPVOID out, LPDWORD outs)
{
    if (!in || !out || !outs)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    *outs = 0;

    HANDLE h = GetProcessHeap();
    DWORD s = 1000;

    LPVOID buf = HeapAlloc(h, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, s);
    if (!buf)
        return FALSE;

    DWORD r = 0;
    while (!DeviceIoControl(dev, code, in, ins, buf, s, &r, 0))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError() || ERROR_MORE_DATA == GetLastError())
        {
            s *= 10;
            LPVOID t = HeapReAlloc(h, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, buf, s);
            if (!t)
            {
                HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
                return FALSE;
            }
            buf = t;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("dic unk: %u\n", GetLastError());
            HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (s > *outs)
    {
        HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
        SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
        return FALSE; 
    }

    CopyMemory(out, buf, s);
    *outs = s;

    HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL getvolptr(HANDLE volh, PRETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb, LPDWORD rpbs)
{
    STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER vcn = { 0 };
    return dic(volh, FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, &vcn, sizeof(vcn), rpb, rpbs);
}
```

```c
HANDLE fi = openfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Kernel32.dll");
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fi)
{
    printf("failed to open file! (%u)\n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
}
else
{
    RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb = { 0 };
    DWORD rpbs = sizeof(rpb);

    if (!getvolptr(fi, &rpb, &rpbs))
    {
        printf("failed to get vol ptrs! (%u)\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        ULONGLONG cluster_cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rpb.ExtentCount; ++i)
        {
            cluster_cnt = (ULONGLONG)(rpb.Extents[i].NextVcn.QuadPart) - (ULONGLONG)(rpb.StartingVcn.QuadPart);
            printf("%d) size: %llu clusters (0x%016X)\n", i, cluster_cnt, rpb.Extents[i].Lcn.QuadPart);
        }
    }

    closefile(fi);
}
```

Alternatively, you can return the pointer to the allocated memory to the caller, and the caller will have to free the memory when done using it, eg:

```c
BOOL dic(HANDLE dev, DWORD code, LPVOID in, DWORD ins, LPVOID* out, LPDWORD outs)
{
    if (!in || !out || !outs)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    *out = NULL;
    *outs = 0;

    HANDLE h = GetProcessHeap();
    DWORD s = 1000;

    LPVOID buf = HeapAlloc(h, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, s);
    if (!buf)
        return FALSE;

    DWORD r = 0;
    while (!DeviceIoControl(dev, code, in, ins, buf, s, &r, 0))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError() || ERROR_MORE_DATA == GetLastError())
        {
            s *= 10;
            LPVOID t = HeapReAlloc(h, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, buf, s);
            if (!t)
            {
                HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
                return FALSE;
            }
            buf = t;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("dic unk: %u\n", GetLastError());
            HeapFree(h, 0, buf);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    *out = buf;
    *outs = s;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL getvolptr(HANDLE volh, PRETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER* rpb, LPDWORD rpbs)
{
    STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER vcn = { 0 };
    return dic(volh, FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, &vcn, sizeof(vcn), (void**)rpb, rpbs);
}
```

```c
HANDLE fi = openfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Kernel32.dll");
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fi)
{
    printf("failed to open file! (%u)\n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
}
else
{
    PRETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER rpb = NULL;
    DWORD rpbs = 0;

    if (!getvolptr(fi, &rpb, &rpbs))
    {
        printf("failed to get vol ptrs! (%u)\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        ULONGLONG cluster_cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rpb->ExtentCount; ++i)
        {
            cluster_cnt = (ULONGLONG)(rpb->Extents[i].NextVcn.QuadPart) - (ULONGLONG)(rpb->StartingVcn.QuadPart);
            printf("%d) size: %llu clusters (0x%016X)\n", i, cluster_cnt, rpb->Extents[i].Lcn.QuadPart);
        }

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, rpb);
    }

    closefile(fi);
}
```